# Parsing SOAP Xml Response to PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, soap

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetExchangeRatesResult"]=> string(6183) " 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 978 EUR ЕМУ 1 61.1876 61.4951 61.8026 EMU евро Euro 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 840 USD С А Д 1 55.2335 55.511 55.7886 USA САД долар US dollar 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 826 GBP В.Британија 1 71.6483 72.0083 72.3684 U.K. британска фунта British pound 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 756 CHF Швајцарија 1 56.1406 56.4227 56.7048 Switzerland швајцарски франк Swiss franc 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 752 SEK Шведска 1 6.4493 6.4817 6.5141 Sweden шведска круна Swedish krona 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 578 NOK Норвешка 1 6.5392 6.5721 6.605 Norway норвешка круна Norwegian krone 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 392 JPY Јапонија 1 0.5402 0.5429 0.5456 Japan јапонски јен Japanese yen 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 208 DKK Данска 1 8.2278 8.2691 8.3105 Denmark данска круна Danish krone 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 124 CAD Канада 1 42.0043 42.2153 42.4264 Canada канадски долар Canadian dollar 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 36 AUD Австралија 1 42.3063 42.5189 42.7315 Australia австралиски долар Australian dollar 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 " }
```

I get the response above from my SOAP request. But am unable to parse it into an array or at the very least Json.

This is what I've tried:

```
$xml = preg_replace(“/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/”, “$1$2$3”, $xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$responseArray = json_decode($json,true);
```

---

When using:

```
function simpleXmlElement2array($xmlObject, $out = array()) {

    foreach ((array)$xmlObject as $index => $node) {
        $out[$index] = (is_object($node) || is_array($node)) ? self::SimpleXmlElement2array($node) : $node;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [GetExchangeRatesResult] => 




























    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    978
    EUR
    ЕМУ
    1
    61.1876
    61.4951
    61.8026
    EMU
    евро
    Euro
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    840
    USD
    С А Д
    1
    55.2335
    55.511
    55.7886
    USA
    САД долар
    US dollar
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    826
    GBP
    В.Британија
    1
    71.6483
    72.0083
    72.3684
    U.K.
    британска фунта
    British pound
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    756
    CHF
    Швајцарија
    1
    56.1406
    56.4227
    56.7048
    Switzerland
    швајцарски франк
    Swiss franc
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    752
    SEK
    Шведска
    1
    6.4493
    6.4817
    6.5141
    Sweden
    шведска круна
    Swedish krona
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    578
    NOK
    Норвешка
    1
    6.5392
    6.5721
    6.605
    Norway
    норвешка круна
    Norwegian krone
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    392
    JPY
    Јапонија
    1
    0.5402
    0.5429
    0.5456
    Japan
    јапонски јен
    Japanese yen
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    208
    DKK
    Данска
    1
    8.2278
    8.2691
    8.3105
    Denmark
    данска круна
    Danish krone
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    124
    CAD
    Канада
    1
    42.0043
    42.2153
    42.4264
    Canada
    канадски долар
    Canadian dollar
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


    149
    2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00
    36
    AUD
    Австралија
    1
    42.3063
    42.5189
    42.7315
    Australia
    австралиски долар
    Australian dollar
    2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00


)
```

I'd at least like to be able to get each item individually like `$arr['12']`

Comment: i was thinking about using explode() to create the array (using the spaces) and from there on forward, it's a dirty solution but it could get the job done.

Comment: I tried that...first used `implode()` then I used `explode()` but doesn't really do it.

Comment: well first you explode the soap response then with that array you make a new one with the first's indexes, and that one you convert to xml

Comment: so whats the $xml before you do xml_load_string, and what is the final result you would like to have

Comment: @sietse85 Instead of exploding I did `$array =  (array) $xml;` The `$xml` is just the soap response — that is displayed with `var_dump` in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time ago I've try recursive approach (it works for node). 
I've found my old code, rmemeber that recursion got limit (You can change it in server settings):

```
public static function SimpleXmlElement2array($xmlObject, $out = array())
{
    foreach ((array)$xmlObject as $index => $node) {
        $out[$index] = (is_object($node) || is_array($node)) ? self::SimpleXmlElement2array($node) : $node;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

**edit:**
Ok no I understand what You want to do.
The problem is invalid data.
When I get string value from the node and try:

```
$temp = explode(' ',  trim($string));
print_r(array_chunk($temp, 13));
```

resluts won't be valid. Every try with explode or parse it using space as delimiter will failed, because of part `840 USD С А Д` should be `840 USD САД`

If not this case, You colud use aboive code. If You got this kind of response with unregular structure, than I don't have an idea how to dandle it without hardcode parse every value using regex.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for...I edited the question with the result I'm getting with ur script, please take a look.